# Do charges made accidentally to the wrong name still get processed?

Tags: banking, international-transfer, wire-transfer

I have an online shop where I use a payment gateway to process credit card payment.

When requesting the payment, I entered my company name in the "Bank Account Holder Name" instead of my personal name. It's a personal account so the holder is my personal name not the company's name.

What will happen to the payment? Will it go through normally since all the other bank account info are 100% accurate (bank name, account number, branch number and SWIFT code)? I tried to contact the payment gateway to report the error but I didn't get any response yet.

Comment: I have noticed that once or twice when I may have entered the wrong account name the payment does go through anyway, but don't know if this is true for all providers and systems.

Comment: Unless there is a dispute by the person whose card you charged and fraud is claimed, you will be fine. They will be processed unless of course they have digital check which matches items of the accounts in which case a computer might deny it but shouldn't be much chance of that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your Bank if they validate the Account Name by word to word comparison. some Banks do, some don't. So the payment would reach your Bank and fail there as they are only ones who can validate the Number & Name. Once the payment fails, it put into a manual queue for further action. Depending on how their error resolution process is [they can send a question back to the Originator saying name does match etc] or simply return the payment. It may be more helpful if you call up your Bank and understand what their processes. If you are a high value customer, they maybe able to process the instruction.